# PostgreSQL systemd service is /bin/true

Tags: postgresql, systemd

`postgresql.service` contents is

```
# systemd service for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on the system. This
# service is actually a systemd target, but we are using a service since
# targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried to start PostrgeSQL by `service postgresql start` and was surprised by   `postgresql.service` contents, because it starts `/bin/true`

`uname -a` output:

```
Linux debian 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt25-2+deb8u3 (2016-07-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So my questions is: Why it happens, and how to fix it?

Comment: Check out this thread. https://askubuntu.com/questions/810008/after-upgrade-14-04-to-16-04-1-postgresql-server-does-not-start

Answer (score 5):

As indicated on the thread by @termcap, `postgresql@{version}-main.service` is the new service name.

So use `systemctl {start|enable} postgresql@9.6-main.service`.

Sensibly the `postgresql.service` should contain a friendly migration warning rather than `/bin/true` (work it out yourself).

Comment: Note that the `postgresql.service` unit also functions as an enable/disable switch for all clusters. If you disable it then all clusters will be disabled, and if you enable any cluster then it will be enabled.

Answer (score -1):

I confirm the issue, OS - xenial, Postgres version - 10 (latest from official repo). frustrating as hell.

Correct file:

```
[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL database server
Documentation=man:postgres(1)

[Service]
Type=notify
User=postgres
ExecStart=/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/10/main/postgresql.conf
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=mixed
KillSignal=SIGINT
TimeoutSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: so what is the fix?

Comment: You just broke the ability to run different cluster ie instances (including the ability to have different versions of postgres) on the same machine. Run in the sense of managing them using systemctl.